# Installing an old version of lme4 package in R

Tags: r, lme4

I am struggling to install the 1.1-13 version of `lme4` package in `R`. I went to https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lme4/ . But I am not understanding the next step after downloading `lme4_1.1-13.tar.gz`. What should I do next?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You do the follow:

```
install.packages("path_to_file/lme4_1.1-13.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Or in the terminal:

```
R CMD INSTALL lme4_1.1-13.tar.gz
```

This second way will not work if the needed system tools for compilation are not present.